# How to convert from scala Iterator[T] to Option[T]

Tags: scala, scala-collections, scala-2.10

I tried to convert an iterator that should return a single item to an equivalent option.

The best I could do was this. Should I use something from standard API?

```
def toUniqueOption[T](a: Iterator[T]): Option[T] =
    if (a.size > 1)
      throw new RuntimeException("The iterator should be emtpy or contain a single item but contained ${a.size} items.")
    else if (a.size > 0)
      Option(a.toList(0))
    else
      Option.empty
```

---

Updated with try

```
def toUnique[T](a: Iterator[T]): Try[Option[T]] =
    if (a.size > 1)
      Failure(new RuntimeException("The iterator should be emtpy or contain a single item but contained ${a.size} items."))
    else if (a.size > 0)
      Success(Option(a.toList(0)))
    else
      Success(Option.empty)
```

Comment: It really is a bad idea to use exceptions to express logic. Consider a type `Either[String, Option[T]]` instead.

Comment: Good ideea. I will try to use Try[T] that I see that can be converted toOption[T]

Answer (score 9):

Calling `size` is risky because it isn't guaranteed to be efficient or even halt.

How about:

```
def toUniqueOption[T](a: Iterator[T]): Option[T] =
  a.take(2).toList match {
    case Nil => None
    case x :: Nil => Some(x)
    case _ => throw new RuntimeException("Iterator size > 1")
  }
```

Answer (score 8):

You could actually use standard API:

```
a.toStream.headOption
```

where a: Iterator[T]

Edit: with scala 2.13+ just use `a.nextOption()`

Comment: Note: `Stream` became `LazyList` in the mean time, you should now use `a.to(LazyList).headOption` instead. But it turns out you could (and should) also just do `a.nextOption()`.

Answer (score 4):

You can avoid iterating the whole sequence using `hasNext` and `next`:

```
def toUniqueOption[T](a: Iterator[T]): Option[T] = {
    if(a.hasNext) {
        val f = a.next()
        if(a.hasNext) throw new RuntimeException("Iterator should contain at most one element")
        Some(f)
    }
    else None
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you ask for, but why not use something like:

```
  def nextAsOption[T](i: Iterator[T]) : Option[T] = {
    i.hasNext match {
      case true  => Some(i.next)
      case false => None
    }
  }
```

This just provides you an Iterator "next" operation that returns an Option rather than a Boolean. Quite handy when you need to pass Options around.

Comment: Why not `if (i.hasNext) Some(i.next) else None`?

Comment: As far as I know it's exactly the same in effect and regarding compiler optimizations.

Comment: I would argue in favor of using a simple `if` for readability.